# Mac OS X - mirroring directories to other disk

Tags: macos

What I need is this:

1) choose some directories on one disk and have these directories mirrored on another disk automatically. For example: suppose I have a directory on diskA called /myFiles and the same directory on diskB. Now, every time I change something on diskA, the changes are echoed to diskB automatically. If I delete a file on diskA, the file is deleted from diskB and so one. A mirror.

Is there a way to have some deamon, service or whatever running on background that allows me to do that on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

NOTE: I know about Time Machine and about rsync and other manual synchronization tools, but what I need is just some directories on one disk to another.

Comment: What about http://synkron.sourceforge.net/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rsync is just what you want, all you will find are rsync GUIs that are a lot less useful than the command line program you already have. Here are some guis - Arsync, backuplist+, dropsync, grsync, synctwofolders.

If Rsync isn't what you want, why?

Folder actions are a pretty easy thing to make, [with limitations.](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10901894)
You could use crontab every five minutes. [Here's one such folder action.](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/automator/syncfoldersaction.html)

Comment: can I make it run on the background or have a service that will fire it automatically and can it just copy what have changed as soon as the directory changes? I need something that is live.

Comment: @Mike See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said "directories", but here is a way to do it with disks. I have the following setup running:

- Linux host A exports a local disk as iSCSI disk
- Linux host B exports a local disk as iSCSI disk

(those two disks are the same size)

- Mac OS X host mounts the two iSCSI disks with the GlobalSAN initiator, and I created a RAID1 volume on them.

Changes are written to both disks at once. The volume can be accessed when at least one iSCSI disk is present. Speed + latency is of course limited by the network.